# Finding an element and clicking on it to navigate to another webpage using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium to open up this webpage (https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzE2ZDIyN2YtODY1Yy00ZGY0LWE4YTktNDcxOTcwYWQyMjM5IiwidCI6IjcyMmVhMGJlLTNlMWMtNGIxMS1hZDZmLTk0MDFkNjg1NmUyNCJ9) and click on the Tram icon to navigate to the web page I want to scrape.

This is what I've tried up to now

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzE2ZDIyN2YtODY1Yy00ZGY0LWE4YTktNDcxOTcwYWQyMjM5IiwidCI6IjcyMmVhMGJlLTNlMWMtNGIxMS1hZDZmLTk0MDFkNjg1NmUyNCJ9")
driver.maximize_window()
x=driver.find_element("class name", "imageBackground")
print(x)

#driver.find_element("class name", "imageBackground").click()
```

However, the element returns none. I'm not sure how to find the element and click the div to navigate to the next page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code.

I added a WebDriverWait that pauses until the tram element is clickable, then it clicks on the Tram element and goes to the next page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

if __name__ == "__main__":
  driver=webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMzE2ZDIyN2YtODY1Yy00ZGY0LWE4YTktNDcxOTcwYWQyMjM5IiwidCI6IjcyMmVhMGJlLTNlMWMtNGIxMS1hZDZmLTk0MDFkNjg1NmUyNCJ9")
  driver.maximize_window()

  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
  tramElementXpath = '//*[@aria-label="Tram Bookmark . Click here to follow link"]'
  x = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, tramElementXpath)))
  x.click()
```